# Server is writing to Database and VB.Net application reading from it in the same time

Tags: sql, database

will this be a problem?

the database will be changing every second when users buy and sell or add items.

and i have a vb.net application in mind and it will not write data to the database but it will be just reading the data with every change.
so one database getting changed thousands of times per hour and a vb.net application graphing and listing that data in real time.

if this doesn't work what are my options?

Comment: while reading data  you can make it page wise( read only a  block of data at a time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what database you're using but some databases (e.g. SQL Server) lock tables when they read so you probably want to be doing a dirty read if the database is being updated all the time.

Comment: i will use whatever database that will make this application function the way i want

Comment: OK, well for argument's sake let's say you're using SQL Server (and you're happy with dirty reads). SQL Server can do this either at statement level or session level.

Comment: so do i have to loop through records or there is some way of telling the application column x row y had changed?

Comment: considering the database has about 66000 records and 17 columns to be read

Comment: There are many ways you could do this. You could have a DATE_UPDATED column or use a trigger...

Comment: DATE_UPDATED...this was my first option but i am not sure about the performance

Comment: You could index the column to make it faster...

Comment: i am thinking about a way to make a log of changed cells so i dont have to loop through every record, like when a change happenes the server sends columnindex/rowindex to the application but i am not sure how to

Comment: You could put code to track column changes in the trigger but this would have to be updated if a column was added.

Comment: so adding a new table with two columns columnindex and row index server write to them and application reads then delete the row..i wonder if this will work fine

Comment: I'm happy to continue commenting but you might get more joy if you raise a separate question for tracking whether a column has changed. Just conscious that what we're discussing is quite different from your original question and the admin get a bit funny about that...

Comment: Bear in mind also that trigger code tends to be the last thing developers check so you might want to add this to the database update code by checking on primary key.

Comment: Thanks for info, now i've something to start with :)